# Unable to preview running app in CodeCatalyst Dev Environment

Tags: ngrok, aws-cloud9, aws-codecatalyst

I am trying to develop a React app in a Code Catalyst Cloud9 based Dev Environment. I am able to run `npm start` to run the development server at `localhost:8080` but cannot find any way to preview the running app.

In a regular Cloud9 instance there's an option to preview a running app:

[image: Preview menu option]

However, there is no such option in the CodeCatalyst environment:

[image: Preview option is missing from menu]

Is this a current limitation of CodeCatalyst? Or is there another way to preview apps that I'm missing? If I have to wait to go through a full deployment pipeline just to see changes, that's going to be a dealbreaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question of the CodeCatalyst team on Slack, and learned that indeed dev environments do not currently support application preview.

That being said, I'm working around the above by using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'm running into the exact same issue. Do you know of any updates to this issue?